# Select rows with max value of a column

Tags: sql

I have a table like the following:

```
acct_id----+---Bill_Id-------+--Bill_dt-----+---alt_bill_id--
12345          123451           02-JAN-2014     101
12345          123452           02-JAN-2014     102 
12346          123461           02-JAN-2014     103
12347          123471           02-JAN-2014     104
```

I need to fetch the data ignoring the least `alt_bill_id` if there are two rows for same `acct_id`. In this case I need to ignore the row for `acct_id` 12345 and alt_bill_id 101. I need a result like the following:

```
 acct_id----+---Bill_Id-------+--Bill_dt-----+---alt_bill_id--
    12345          123452           02-JAN-2014     102 
    12346          123461           02-JAN-2014     103
    12347          123471           02-JAN-2014     104
```

Comment: Does anyone think this is bad database design?

Comment: This one is not my design. It was designed by someone else but I am given a job with this.

Comment: @AliGajani Not necessarily, without more context. If this is a table of bills, and `Bill_Id` is the primary key, with `acct_id` as a foreign key into an accounts table, I don't see a problem. I don't know what `alt_bill_id` is but it doesn't scream "this design is bad" at me.

Comment: Having duplicate id is against the principles of normalization. Obviously, it works, but it can be improved upon. But anyway, I was just thinking I'd do it differently

Comment: @AliGajani You mean the fact that there are two entries with the same `acct_id`? I think you are missing the fact that `acct_id` is probably not the primary key, `Bill_Id` is. This table is normalized. Regardless, this has nothing to do with the OP's question; as he said, he did not design the table.

Comment: Yes, I just had a closer look. My bad :)

Answer (score 5):

You have to use a sub-query to find the highest value(`bill_id`), then join to that sub-query. Like this:

```
SELECT main.* FROM my_table AS main
  JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(bill_id) AS bill_id
         FROM my_table 
     GROUP BY acct_id
        ) AS highest
  ON highest.bill_id = main.bill_id;
```

And here is the SQLFiddle for anyone who wishes to try it out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc66a/2

Comment: Please see the question. He wants the maximum value only. I thought your query was right until I tested it out. It's not, at least that's what the SQLFiddle showed.

Comment: The maximum value of the bill_id or the alt_bill_id? you put the same bill_id in, they were both the maximum

Comment: Okay wait, I might have entered the wrong data. Let me re-do. Sorry for the fuss. Here it is. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc66a/2

Answer (score 0):

I have used the query like this:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM CI_BILL T1
WHERE ALT_BILL_ID IN (SELECT MAX(ALT_BILL_ID)
FROM CI_BILL T2 GROUP BY T2.ACCT_ID);
```